# How to retrieve xsi:schemaLocation with xercesc::SAX2XMLReader

Tags: c++, xml, xsd, xerces-c

I use a [SAX2XMLReader](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classSAX2XMLReader.html) to parse an XML file that specifies an XSD schema by having the attribute xsi:schemaLocation in its root element.

How can I retrieve the string value of this attribute?

I tried

```
parser->getProperty(XMLUni::fgXercesSchemaExternalSchemaLocation)
```

but it returns a `nullptr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a class MyPSVIHandler that inherits from [PSVIHandler](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classPSVIHandler.html) and install it with the `setPSVIHandler` method.

```cpp
MyPSVIHandler psvi_handler;
sax2xmlreader->setPSVIHandler(&psvi_handler);
```

```cpp
void MyPSVIHandler::handleAttributesPSVI(
    const XMLCh *const /* localName */,
    const XMLCh *const /* uri */,
    PSVIAttributeList *psviAttributes) {
  for (XMLSize_t i = 0; i < psviAttributes->getLength(); i++) {
    if (XMLString::equals(psviAttributes->getAttributeNamespaceAtIndex(i),
                          SchemaSymbols::fgURI_XSI)) {
      const XMLCh *attr_name(psviAttributes->getAttributeNameAtIndex(i));
      if (XMLString::equals(attr_name, SchemaSymbols::fgXSI_SCHEMALOCATION)) {
        const XMLCh *str = psviAttributes->
            getAttributePSVIAtIndex(i)->getSchemaNormalizedValue();
        char *transcoded_str = xercesc::XMLString::transcode(str);
        std::cout << "schemaLocation = " << transcoded_str << "\n";
        xercesc::XMLString::release(&transcoded_str);
      }
    }
  }
}
```